# Mencionar usuario que realizo el comando con Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy intentando usar **Discord.py** para programar bots para Discord pero me encontré con el ligero problema que no encuentro manera alguna de mencionar al usuario que "llamo" o realizo al comando.

Me dijeron que era posible usando `ctx.message.author` pero no lo logré hacer funcionar.

Código que intento usar:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
...
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='Ejemplo')
...
@client.command()
async def prueba(texto : str):
    print('Comando de prueba ejecutado, texto recibido: ' + texto)
    await client.say(ctx.message.author + ':ok_hand:')
```

Comment: Buenas George, bienvenido. Puedes mostrar como llamas a la funcion `prueba`? puedes pasar el contexto como parametro? Un saludo

Comment: Es un comando de Discord, lo menciona con `@client.command()`. Se ejecuta al escribir !prueba

Comment: Puedo pasar el contexto usando `@client.command(pass_context=True)`, pero no sabría como usarlo. Anteriormente usaba `{0.author.mention}` pero interceptaba todos los comandos y los enviaba a la consola.

Comment: Mira a ver si esto es de ayuda: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-original-message

Comment: Lo había visto e intentado usar, pero no entrega la "mención". La idea es que le llegue la notificación al usuario.

Comment: Pues hasta ahí la ayuda que puedo ofrecer, espero que tengas suerte con la pregunta. un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por actualizar un poco la respuesta, desde la versión `1.0` (Abril de 2019) [`pass_context=True` ya no existe](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_to_v1.html#command-extension-changes).

Context se debe pasar siempre como parámetro de la función (y con eso es suficiente para poder acceder a este).

Además, como se puede ver en el [changelog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_to_v1.html#removed-helpers), `client.say()` fue eliminado en la versión `1.0`. Ahora se debe usar [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send):

```
@client.command(name='prueba')
async def prueba(ctx : commands.Context, texto : str = ''):
    print(f'Comando de prueba ejecutado, texto recibido: {texto}')
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} ')
```

Y por terminar de completar, desde la versión `2.0` (Agosto de 2022) [es necesario especificar los `Intents` al inicializar el bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#intents-are-now-required) y, para poder acceder al contenido de los mensajes enviados (y, por tanto, poder usar el comando) es necesario activar el intent [`message_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content).

Esta sería una forma actualizada de inicializar el bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Por último, habría que ir al [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) a habilitarle a la aplicación dicho `"Privileged" Intent`. Esto solo es necesario hacerlo una vez (por bot):

1. Selecciona `Aplicaciones` en el panel de la izquierda y a continuación selecciona tu aplicación. En mi caso, sería *"test"*:

[image: Paso 1]

2. Una vez dentro de la aplicación, nuevamente en el panel de la izquierda, selecciona la pestaña `Bot`:

[image: Paso 2]

3. Una vez en la pestaña `Bot`, *"scrollea"* hasta que veas la sección `Privileged Gateway Intents`. Habilita el `message content intent`:

[image: Paso 3]

Answer (score 3):

@lois6b estuvo demasiado cerca. Hay que pasarle el contexto al comando para que pueda utilizarlo y después formatear el texto usando variables:

```
# Importa Discord.py
import discord
# Importa los Comandos de Discord.py
from discord.ext import commands
...
# Crea el cliente aka Bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='Ejemplo')
...
# Define la sección como comando
# pass_context=True le envía el contexto
@client.command(pass_context=True)
# ctx = contexto
# texto = texto despues del comando
async def prueba(ctx, texto : str):
    # Escribe en la consola el texto recibido
    print('Comando de prueba ejecutado, texto recibido: ' + texto)
    # Almacena el nombre del autor en la variable "usuario"
    usuario = ctx.message.author
    # Formatea el texto en donde 0=usuario y "mention" es la mención a este
    await client.say('{0.mention} :ok_hand:'.format(usuario))
```

Comment: Así funciona? :D Recuerda que aunque te respondas a ti mismo has de explicar la solucion como si fueras otra persona. Explica qué habia mal en la pregunta y como se resuelve en tu respuesta :P así futuras personas podrán entenderlo tambien. En 48h podrás aceptar la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Recibo sin problemas `@Username#1234 :ok_hand:` dentro de Discord (nótese el @)

Comment: Me alegro. Mira [lo que te comenté](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65835/mencionar-usuario-que-realizo-el-comando-con-discord-py#comment120045_65841) y [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65841/edit) la respuesta para incluir esa informacion. [es.so] busca la mayor calidad en preguntas y respuestas^^

Comment: Listo @lois6b , ahí "complete" la pregunta explicando el procedimiento.

Comment: perfecto, mañana podrás aceptar la respuesta